# Why sending a request to controller using Postman runs fine but using RestTemplate throws 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, controller, postman

**Context**

I have two controllers: `/testParams` and `/callTestParams`
Controller `/testParams` receives an object of type Example and I can call this controller from Postman without any problem.

Controller `/callTestParams` calls `/testParams` internally using **RestTemplate** but the response is a 500 Internal Server Error. I supose that the implementation of `/callTestParams` is equivalent to the call maded by Postman.

Here is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testParams",
            method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> testParams(            
            @RequestBody Example credentials
    ) {


        JSONObject params = new JSONObject( credentials );

        System.out.println( params.get("clientId") + " from JSONObject");
        System.out.println( credentials.getClientId() + " from GraphCredentials");


        return new ResponseEntity<>(credentials,HttpStatus.OK);
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/callTestParams",
            method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> callTestParams() {

        String url = "http://localhost:8080/GraphClient/testParams";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.set( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE );

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("clientId", "value1" );

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(params,headers);

        HttpEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(
          url,
          HttpMethod.POST,
          entity,
          Object.class
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**This is the response from Postman for /testParams**

**Headers:**
(Content-Type,application/json)

**Request Body:**
JSON (appplication/json)

```
{"clientId":"value1"}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "clientId": "value1",
    "clientSecret": null,
    "tenantId": null,
    "scope": null,
    "grantType": null,
    "microsoftLoginBaseURL": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"
}
```

**This is the response from Postman for /callTestParams**

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-01-09T03:39:06.878+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "500 Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/GraphClient/callTestParams"
}
```

This is the error in the console>

Forwarding to error page from request [/testParams] due to exception [JSONObject["clientId"] not found.]: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["clientId"] not found.

[image]

Comment: Remove params from testParams method

Comment: @Sabila2022 the 500 error response should have an exception produced in the backend. Check the logs and update the question with that exception.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos  Forwarding to error page from request [/testParams] due to exception [JSONObject["clientId"] not found.]: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["clientId"] not found.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos Obviusly  the question says> "I supose that the implementation of /callTestParams is equivalent to the call maded by Postman."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the parameter of the body of the HttpEntity constructor you need to pass params as String

```
HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(params.toString(),headers);
```